# How can I prevent overflow-x auto from causing a vertical scroll bar?

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, css-position

I have a flex container which displays a horizontal scroll bar when the number of flex items exceeds the available viewport width.

This works fine until I add a pseudo element (down caret) to one of the items, causing a vertical scroll bar to appear.

As expected, adding `overflow-y: hidden` to my container will hide part of my pseudo element. So my question is how can I prevent a vertical scroll bar when trying to independently set the x-axis to 'auto' only?

[JS Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/q1skw6vn/11/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS overflow-x: visible; and overflow-y: hidden; causing scrollbar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue)

Comment: It's a common problem (literally hundreds of similar questions on SO). An absolutely-positioned element, as it is removed from the document flow, will not expand the parent height, but it will trigger an overflow condition. A simple solution would be to set the height of the parent to include the abspos pseudo-element.

Answer (score 0):

Then you want add the extra `space` to avoid `Vertical Scroll` .

You can achieve this just add extra space on `.hud-card` this selecter.

```
.hud-card {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```